# Dynamic folder finding using perl

Tags: regex, perl

Am new to perl and we have a requirement to pickup files from folder that gets created everyday.
 Is there any way we can do this like using sysdate or anything?
 Path will be something like http:\\com.test.ci\test01
\new_folder_created_daily\*.*
Is there anyway to dynamically get this done ?

Comment: you need a naming convention for the daily created folders, something with date/timestamps will be the best

Comment: Yes. Folder convention will be something like MMDDYYYY.

Comment: another thing, what exactly do you mean by picking up files. Do you want to copy them somewhere else, or just print out the list of file names.

Comment: we already have a script that copies the files from this path to other paths. All we have to do is supply it with path from where it has to pickup files.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do that you need help with? Are you asking for help constructing a path containing the current date?

Comment: yes. that's the thing. is there any regex involved in it ?

Comment: Do you have to use perl or can you go with a specialised tool such as *wget*?

Comment: only perl is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making assumptions that you want to act on just the most recently created folder. I'm also going to assume you want to wait until the next day as maybe the folder is written to throughout the day... If not, just ignore the `$yesterday` stuff and use `$today` instead.

Use Time::Piece and Time::Seconds, which have been a core module since 5.009005.

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $today = localtime;
my $yesterday = $today - ONE_DAY;
my $folder = $yesterday->mdy("");

print $folder . "\n"

# do stuff to http:\\com.test.ci\test01\$folder
```

Basically we create a Time::Piece object and minus one day from it using a contant from Time::Seconds to create `$yesterday`. We don't really care about the time, so format it as `mdy` and append it to your parent path.

The mdy("") just means no delimter between the m, d and y. If you instead wrote `$yesterday->mdy()`, it would format it as MM-DD-YYYY. Refer to [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.29/Piece.pm) on CPAN for more information on date formatting, calculations, comparisons, and parsing.